# Why is Jackson TypeReference abstract?

Tags: java, jackson

Why is Jackson's TypeReference abstract? It generally makes usages uglier since you need to include braces to create an inline class (and most linters force you into no curly braces on same line).

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java

```
new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
};
```

Is this due to some obscure Java language limitation?

Comment: @JBNizet make that an answer, so that I can +1

Comment: @MauricePerry I should have done that from the start. Done now.

Comment: Really don't agree with the downvotes on this one - it may have a clear, reasonably straightforward answer to those "in the know", but the fact generic information is preserved at runtime by subclassing is a bit of a niche fact in and of itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JB Nizet has answered why. I just wanted to demonstrate the principle of action.

You can try this for yourself on other classes:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>() {};

System.out.println(a.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
System.out.println(b.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/i2GNv0)

Output:

```
java.util.AbstractList<E> 
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
```

As you can see, creating the anonymous subclass preserves the type information about what the concrete generic type of the list is at runtime.

A `TypeReference` does much the same:

```
new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() { }
```

has a generic superclass:

```
 TypeReference<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>>
```

and from this, you can get the type `Map<String, String>`. If you created a type reference for another type:

```
    new TypeReference<Map<Integer, Integer>>() { };
```

you could get the type `Map<Integer, Integer>>`, which is separate from `Map<String, String>`.

If `TypeReference` were non-abstract, you could write:

```
TypeReference<Map<String, String>> p = new TypeReference<>();
TypeReference<Map<Integer, Integer>> q = new TypeReference<>();
```

but the types of `p` and `q` would be indistinguishable.

Answer (score 7):

Precisely to force you to create a subclass, because it's the only way to capture the generic type.

It's written in the very first sentence of the javadoc that you linked to:

> This generic abstract class is used for obtaining full generics type information **by sub-classing**.

(emphasis mine).

The documentation also has a link to a blog post explaining that principle.

Comment: I understand that it’s required to capture the type. I guess I’m trying to understand why java behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself has already been answered, but i'd like to provide a solution to the problem of the code being ugly due to having to use curly braces and occupy an extra line.

Normally it's used like this:

```java
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<>() {
});
```

It's not too bad, but it may be annoying to some. So, there is a way to avoid it by using a `JavaType`. You can create a utility method:

```java
private <K, V> JavaType mapType(Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass) {
    return objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Map.class, keyClass, valueClass);
}
```

and use it like this:

```java
Map<String, String> map = objectMapper.readValue(file, mapType(String.class, String.class));
```

Same can be done for Lists and other collections.